# How to make an iframe fill an area defined by distance from edges?

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe which I want to fill all of an area on the page specified by the bottom, right, left, and top css styles.  However, when I do the method I would expect to work, it does not:

HTML:

`<iframe id="example_frame" src="http://example.com"></iframe>`
CSS:

```
#example_frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
}
```

This results in a little box with the web page about 100x100 pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because `iframes` are [replaced elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements), you can't just set any combination of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`. Should you be able to? Absolutely. But you can't. Instead, you can set one vertical property (`top` or `bottom`), one horizontal property (`left` or `right`), and then set both `height` and `width` to `100%`.

To achieve the effect you are going for where there's a `1em` space around the iframe, simply wrap the `iframe` in another non-replaced element like a `div`.

```
<div class="abs-frame-container">
  <iframe id="example_frame" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

The CSS that produces the effect you're going for is:

```
.abs-frame-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
}

.abs-frame-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also look out for issues where setting `border: 0` in CSS won't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning works with one x and one y coordinate at a time. I'm guessing the browser is ignoring one set of your coordinates.

Also, since you haven't specified a with or a height for the iframe, it is defaulting to 100 x 100.

Try something like:

```
#example_frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: the code I have works for a div, how is the iframe any different?

Comment: 1) iframes by default are inline elements;

2) iframes require width and height designations, even when display is set to block.  I.e., "block" actually behaves like "inline-block" for iframes.

Comment: "Absolute position works with one x and one y coordinate at a time." This is wrong although the proposed solution is correct. I think the problem has something to do with iframes being replaced elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but don't you have to define the iframe as `position: absolute to be able to set a size in terms of the browser window;`? I'd imagine it's `display:block` by default?

---

Edited in response to comment from OP.

What doctype are you using? Does the problem occur in all browsers/platforms you can test on? Are you successfully calling the stylesheet? Are you using inline styles, styles in the head or an external sheet?

If you're not using inline-styles, try using them, just for a moment, to see if they work inline, or not.